# How do I pack dataframes in a set or reference them without mutating them? Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, memory-management, set, immutability

I have 3 pd.DataFrame objects: A, B and C. I want to summarise them in a set (eg: set(A,B,C)) because I want to loop through a list and do things to it but I also don't want to mutate the dataframes or have it in a new dictionary (basically want to save some memory).

EDIT: `set(A,B,C)` gave an error: set expected at most 1 arguments, got 3. I tried `{A,B,C}` and got: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed. So the question is how can I reference them without mutating them?

The code is:

```
A = pd.DataFrame([random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(100)])
B = pd.DataFrame([random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(100)])
C = pd.DataFrame([random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(100)])
set(A,B,C) # gets error: set expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
{A,B,C} # gets error: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
for key in datasets:
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1,sharex=True)
    temp = key
    temp.plot(ax=axes[0], grid=True, color="k")
    axes[0].set(ylabel=f"{key}")
    key.rolling(4, center=True).var().plot(ax=axes[1],grid=True, color="b")
    axes[1].set(xlabel="Date")
```

The code is pretty self explanatory but to reiterate, I want a 2 row, 1 col subplot with the data in top row and rolling window variance in the bottom and a shared x-axis on the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for rephrasing and including sample data. Now I see that your question is not about matplotlib because what you want to know is how to use  `set(A,B,C)`. This is more a `pandas` related problem. I would suggest you to remove matplotlib tag and put pandas tag

Comment: I think the proper approach here is simply to use a list or dict instead of a set. Try replacing the set lines with `datasets = [A, B, C]`. None of your code will mutate the DataFrames, so you don't need `temp`.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler doing so, datasets would be a new object? I want to save memory without replicating the df as well

Comment: Inserting the DataFrames into a list won't replicate them. And even if it did... if the code runs fine on your size of data, who cares about the memory footprint? :P

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete because no one can run your code without having access to your data. Nevertheless, you can try something like this. The idea is to define the figure object just once outside the for loop

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1,sharex=True)

for key in datasets:  
    key.plot(ax=axes[0], grid=True, color="k")
    axes[0].set_ylabel(f"{key}")
    key.rolling(4, center=True).var().plot(ax=axes[1],grid=True, color="b")
    axes[1].set_xlabel("Date")
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I couldn't upload the datasets because I imported them as csv and they're quite large. Would it be possible to generate random values in an array and convert to df for the sake of ease?
pd.DataFrame([random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(100)])

Comment: @ShervinRad: Did you try out my suggestion?

Comment: yes but I got that error so it never made it to the plot

Comment: I am sorry but I can't proceed unless you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which I can directly run to reproduce the error.

Comment: Apologies, I have rephrased the question. I think if that problem is addressed, combined with your answer, the problem should be fixed. Many thanks for your help!